# PL SQL procedure with select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to execute procedure that returns me the First name, last name and the title of the author based on the state he/she is from.
But the code above returns me PLS-00103 error "end-of-file".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1 (stattt OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN
SELECT a.au_fname, a.au_lname, t.title
FROM authors a, titleauthor ta, titles t 
WHERE ta.au_id = a.au_id
AND t.title_id = ta.title_id
AND state =  stattt
/
```

I also tried to use

```
into proc1
```

but it is still doesnt work.
This is from the sample database Pubs from MS SQL that I converted to SQL Oracle.

Comment: you missed `END;` and also you can't just select in Oracle procedure as you did in ms sql

Comment: @IliaMaskov . . . And the query is also missing `JOIN` and `ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few objections:

- you already know that `END` is missing
- apart from that, `INTO` is required for a `SELECT` statement in PL/SQL (i.e. you have to put the result *somewhere*). Usually, you declare local variables for that purpose. You chose to return ref cursor - OK
- `stattt` is ref cursor, set as an out parameter for that procedure; I don't think that you can use it as a parameter in that WHERE clause.

Here's an example based on Scott's schema (as I don't have your tables) which shows how to do that. I'm returning all employees that work in some department (10, in this example):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test (par_deptno   IN     NUMBER,
  2                                      par_rc          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5     OPEN par_rc FOR
  6        SELECT empno, ename, sal
  7          FROM emp
  8         WHERE deptno = par_deptno;
  9  END;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var l_rc refcursor
SQL>
SQL> exec p_test(10, :l_rc);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_rc

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK            2450
      7839 KING            10000
      7934 MILLER           1300

SQL>
```

Comment: Alternatively, with a modern Oracle version, use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT();`

Answer (score 0):

Follow  [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm) syntax and the convention that every beginning has an **end**, and close BEGIN with END:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1 (stattt OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN
SELECT a.au_fname, a.au_lname, t.title
FROM authors a, titleauthor ta, titles t 
WHERE ta.au_id = a.au_id
AND t.title_id = ta.title_id
AND state =  stattt
END;
/
```

> ```
> Header AS
> [declaration statements
>   ...]
> BEGIN
>   ...
> [EXCEPTION
>   ...]
> END;
> ```